# How to work with files in the ChromeOS My Files app?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, manifest.json, google-chrome-os

I am currently working on a Chrome extension and facing a challenge related to file handling in ChromeOS's My Files application. My objective is to develop functionality that allows users to manipulate files, specifically for encrypting files and appending an `.enc` extension to the file names.

### What I already tried

#### chrome.fileBrowserHandler

Initially, I attempted to use chrome.fileBrowserHandler, but in the [Manifest V3 issue tracker](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/develop/migrate/known-issues) it links to file handlers. Also, I couldn't get the fileBrowserHandler to work with the My Files app.

#### file_handlers

Subsequently, I explored using [file_handlers](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/manifest/file-handlers) in the manifest. However, this method appears to restrict operations to files with known MIME types, which limits my ability to universally apply encryption to all file types. Also, I do not know how to actually manipulate the file extension or file content and pass it back from the JavaScript to the file manager.

### Questions

I am seeking advice or suggestions on how to effectively approach this problem. Ideally, I need a method to:

1. Allow my extension to manipulate any file type in the My Files application.
2. Perform operations like encryption and rename the file with e.g. an `.enc` extension.

Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated!